# Why all the paths jump to the root path（vue-router)?

Tags: vue-router

I initialized a project with the vue-cli,and I just configured the router.
why is always open the 'HelloWorld' component when I try to enter: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld2' or 'http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld1'.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import HelloWorld1 from '@/components/HelloWorld1'
import HelloWorld2 from '@/components/HelloWorld2'
import HelloWorld3 from '@/components/HelloWorld3'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [
       {
           path: '/',
           name: 'HelloWorld',
           component: HelloWorld
       },
       {
           path: '/HelloWorld1',
           component: HelloWorld1,
           // childres:[
           //     {
           //         path: 'HelloWorld3',
           //         component: HelloWorld3,
           //     },
           // ]
       },
       {
           path: '/HelloWorld2',
           component: HelloWorld2
       }
   ]
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vue-router uses hash mode by default. In your configuration, you probably want to use html5 history mode. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations for reference.

This can be changed in your Router setup:

`const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})`